# Child process output sometimes considered coming from parent process?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a few Node.js scripts I load along with my app. I want to keep those jobs as modular as possible so that's why I'm using child processes. Here is the code to load my job files :

```
var job_files = glob.sync('**/*.js', {cwd: __dirname+'/jobs'});

var child_processes = [];
async.each(job_files, function(job_file, cb) {
  var i = job_files.indexOf(job_file);
  child_processes[i] = exec('node '+__dirname+'/jobs/'+job_file);
  child_processes[i].stdout.on('data', function(data) {
    // Regex to eliminate extra new lines
    console.log('[w%s] %s', i, data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""));
  });
  child_processes[i].stderr.on('data', function(data) {
    console.log('[w%s] %s', i, data.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, ""));
  });
  child_processes[i].on('close', function(code) {
    console.log('[w%s] Exit code: %s', i, code);
  });
}, function(err) {
  console.log('Jobs loaded!');
});
```

As you can see, I prepend a little tag before every console output coming from my child processes so I can identify which job outputs which message.

It works great most of the time, but sometimes (randomly, it seems to me) a message originating from a child process won't have a tag before it, as if it had been output by the parent process.

Is there something wrong with the way I handle my child processes (or my tagging)?

Comment: Are you sure it's not just the async nature of console.log making things look out of order?

Comment: Yeah I was thinking something like that could be the cause of this, but I don't really see how I could do it otherwise ...